# Convert Double to string with exponential notation

Tags: c#

Step : 1

I have a value saved in Sql Server DB "-3.507828666035941e-04".

Step : 2

After retrieving this value from DB i am converting it to double i am getting "-0.00035078286660359412". Am converting this value because i have to pass as a argument in service method. Argument type is double

Step : 3

After convert that to string i get "-0.000350782866603594".  In the service method they are converting it to string to append in string builder

**My question is:**

What conversion i should do again to get back "-3.507828666035941e-04" value?

I tried to convert "-0.000350782866603594" in the reverse step 3,2,1
I am not getting the required value

Comment: If you want the database value why are you converting it to a double at all in the first place?

Comment: Try `value.ToString("E", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: `I have a value saved in Sql Server DB "-3.507828666035941e-04".` - You surely haven't? I take it your field in the db table is of type float and you only see it _displayed_ in E notation?

Comment: if i want to save "-3.507828666035941e-04" into double variable. i have to convert that right

Comment: i have a service that has a parameter type is double. to that parameter i have to pass  "-3.507828666035941e-04"

Comment: ya. In the seervice method this value is converted to string to append in String Builder

Comment: If your service parameter is double, you can't pass it "-3.507828666035941e-04", as it is a string

Comment: that's y i am converting it to double

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question seems a nonsense to me. Floating point math has this type of problems, it's not exact. If you want your original value, save it for using it afterwards.

Comment: If you really want to know why that happens, you can read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). But i warn you It's not an easy read :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert it this way

```
double d = -0.00035078286660359412;
string s = d.ToString("0.000000000000000e00");
```

Comment: The output that i get is -3.5078E-004

Comment: Is it possible to get full value like this -3.507828666035941e-04

Comment: super. i tried to get this whole "-3.507828666035941e-04" value. So i tried ur suggested answer ToString("0.000000000000000e00") by adding. But i got -3.507828666035940e-04 Instead i want -3.507828666035941e-04

Comment: cool I have added your approach too at my answer, happy coding :)

Comment: :)  How to get that 41e at the end instead of 40e. Is my question clear

Comment: that means the 1 last digit ?

Comment: i mean the number "1" available at the end (near e) "-3.507828666035941e-04"

Comment: during conversion some fractions are auto rounded